Can I turn a Schwarzschild black hole into a Kerr black hole by dropping a spinning particle into it?
Pardon any obvious oversight, I have rediscovered my love and curiosity for astrophysics after ages. Initially, the black hole would be described by a Schwarzschild Metric, and then a Kerr Metric after it "absorbs" the particle and its spin. Does GR allow for these types of transitions between metrics or does the mathematics assume that non=spinning/spinning black holes always have and always will be described by the same metrics? If it does "convert" the black hole, at what instant of the process does the metric change?
The other related questions of the website have mentioned that no analytic situations exist for such a complex scenario, is it possible to simulate such a scenario numerically?

A Schwarzschild black hole is a Kerr black hole for the special case of $0$ angular momentum.

a point singularity is a ring singularity with radius zero, you have a point

The Schwarzschild metric is eternal - it cannot be changed (by definition).

@HritikNarayan “a point singularity is a ring singularity with radius zero, you have a point” - This is incorrect. The Schwarzschild singularity is not a point, but an infinitely long line: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400 - When you add angular momentum, this line becomes thicker representing a cylinder of the inner horizon. So the equivalent of the Schwarzschild singularity in the Kerr metric is not the ring singularity, but the Cauchy horizon.

@HritikNarayan As others already mentioned, Schwarzschild and Kerr are eternal unchangeable abstractions. You cannot drop anything into one to convert it to the other. You can however drop a spinning particle to a non-rotating star collapsing to approximate Schwarzschild in the future and this would change the collapse to eventually approximate Kerr instead.

Yes actually. Because angular momentum is conserved, considering the post-absorption black hole would require considering the angular momentum of the absorbed particle, which would be most accurately described by the Kerr solution if the particle is otherwise neutral.
Here's an issue though: when does the particle become part of the black hole? It has been proven that the event horizon cannot be crossed from either side in a finite amount of coordinate time; barring evaporation, it will take literally forever for the particle to reach the event horizon. In reality you'd have to consider the particle as perpetually-separate from the black hole, thus requiring a numeric simulation-like solution as you note. In principle though, if you are allowed to wait $\infty$ seconds (or equivalently years or attoseconds) you could treat the particle as having successfully crossed the event horizon and created a Kerr black hole - thing is you can't do that, so there's the issue.

This answer is essentially correct. The downvote is unjustified +1

Some heuristic arguments can be drawn from Extreme mass ratio inspirals: Assume two Schwarzschild (schw) like BHs of masses $M$ and $m$ with $M>>m$ free-falling towards one another from infinity. Let's say BH $m$ also has some initial orbital angular momentum $l_0$ , but since they are infinitely far away, you could assume their momentum to be practically zero. So we have two schw BHs and the total entropy should be sum of their individual area of EH: $$S_{in}=\frac{1}{4}((2M)^2+(2m)^2)$$
Now, if they asymptotically merge to form a Kerr BH with angular momentum $l$, you could estimate an upper-bound from the inequality $$S_{final}>S_{initial}$$ which yields $|l|< \sqrt{8Mm}$. However, in this estimate we assumed that the masses of BH remains the same through out, which isn't true: the GW emitted by the system will reduce the mass of the source as well as the total angular momentum. To estimate these quantities you could model the space-time by some class of Weyl metric governed solely by the heavy mass $M$ with the point mass $m$ orbiting around it like a test particle. In this approximation, there will be loss in the energy and angular momentum due to the time varying Quadrupole Moment of the mass $m$ ($Q^{ij}=\int d^3xx^ix^jT^{tt}(t,x)$ and $h_{ij}\sim \ddot{Q}_{ij}$). The angular momentum of $m$ would change at the rate of $\dot{l}^i\sim \epsilon^{ijk}\int d^2x \langle\ddot{Q}_{ja}\ddot{Q}_{ka}\rangle$ while $\dot{E}\sim (\dddot{Q}_{ij}\dddot{Q}^{ij})$. You could proceed to calculate the net change in $l$ and $m$ over the entire time of flight and see whether the upper bound is satisfied or not for a given choice of $l_0$ and $m$. And once the merge is complete we could argue that the resulting spacetime is locally isometric to Kerr due to it's uniqueness property
